# React Native developer menu is not showing in android debug build

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, react-devtools

Blank white screen is coming instead of developer menu in android debug build.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUn42.jpg)

Compared sample project android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml with my AndroidManifest file found  this line was missing in my project, Have added the same line but still not working.

Comment: Does it work when you click on it? It could be a theme problem where both the fonts and backgrounds are white, whereas the menu items are still there. I encountered similar issues in the past.

Comment: Yes all options are working on click.